# Inverse Fourier Transform Formula on $L^2.$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $dt$ be the reduced Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R,$ and $L^1$ and $L^2$ be the associated function spaces. There is an isometry $$f\mapsto \hat f:L^1\cap L^2\to L^2$$ given by $$\hat f(t)=\int f(x)e^{-ixt}dx.$$

Furthermore, since $L^1\cap L^2$ is dense in $L^2$, the map extends to an isometry from all of $L^2$ onto $L^2.$

The problem is to prove that if $f\in L^2$ and $\hat f\in L^1$ then the usual inversion formula holds a.e.: $$f(x)=\int \hat f(t)e^{ixt}dt.$$

We have, with $\chi_n$ the characteristic function on $[-n,n],\ \chi_n\cdot \hat f\to \hat f$ and since $\hat f\in L^1,$ the Dominated Convergence theorem applies to show that $$\lim \int \chi_n(t)\cdot \hat f(t)e^{ixt}dt=\int \hat f(t)e^{ixt}dt.$$ Thus, we have to show that $f_n(x):=\int \chi_n(t)\cdot \hat f(t)e^{ixt}dt\to f(x).$

The crux of this seems to be showing that $f_n(x)=\chi_n(x)\cdot f(x).$

Using the isometry, I have been able to show that $f_n\to f$ in the $L^2$ norm, so there is an a.e. pointwise convergent subsequence, but this seems like a dead end.

If it turned out that $f_n$ was the inverse transform of $\chi_n\cdot \hat f,$ that would be enough also, but I do not see any reason for this to be true. The map $f\to \hat f$ maps $L^1\cap L^2$ onto a dense subspace of $L^2$, but there is no reason to suppose that it is $L^1\cap L^2$, or is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f\in L^2$, then $\hat{f}\in L^2$, and
$$
          L^2-\lim_n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-n}^{n}\hat{f}(s)e^{isx}ds = f.
$$
So there is a subsequence in $n$ so that the inverse integral over $[-n,n]$ converges pointwise a.e. to $f$. However, the pointwise inversion integral exists for all $x$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ because $\hat{f}\in L^1$. Therefore,
$$
             f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(s)e^{isx}ds,\;\; a.e. x\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
If you knew $f$ were continuous everywhere, then equality would hold everywhere because a.e. equality for two continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ implies equality everywhere.

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to +1 etc, but this is a very clear proof so --thanks.

Comment: @Driver8 : You're allowed to +1 answers to your questions. Thank you. :)

Comment: I have a question. To prove the fact that $L^2-\lim_n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-n}^{n}\hat{f}(s)e^{isx}ds = f,$ I thought it was an easy application of the isometry: $\Phi:f\mapsto \hat f,$ as in this calculation: $\int \chi_{[-n,n]}(t)\cdot f(t)e^{-ixt}dt= (\chi\cdot f)^{\wedge}$ so $\|\hat f-(\chi\cdot f)^{\wedge}\|_2=\|(f-(\chi\cdot f))^{\wedge}\|_2=\|f-\chi\cdot f\|_2\to 0\ - L^2.$ But this trick does not seem to work going the other way, because I  don't know how to handle $\chi\cdot \hat f.$

Comment: @Driver8 : The Fourier transform and the inverse transforms are isometric. There's only a negative in the exponent that distinguishes the two, which is an isometric operation on $L^2$.

Comment: @ DisintegratingByParts: The map that sends $f\in L^1\cap L^2$ to $\hat f$ via the formula $\int f(x)e^{-ixt}dt$ maps onto a dense subspace $Y$ of $L^2$. The map extends to an isometry $\Phi$, of $L^2$ onto $L^2$ ,and  the formula for the inverse transform is (only?) valid on $Y$ but my understanding of Plancherel is that the inverse formula is approximate  off $Y$, i.e. true in the $L^2$ limit.and although $\chi \hat f\in L^1\cap L^2$, but it may not be in $Y$ --cont...below

Comment: so  if $\phi(x)=\int \chi(t)\hat f(t)e^{ixt}dt$, how can I conclude that $\phi=\Phi^{-1}(\chi f)?$ I need this fact if I want to argue, using the isometry (the trick in my previous comment) that $\|\phi-\hat f\|_2\to 0.$

Comment: @Driver8 : If $f\in L^2$, then $\chi_{[-n,n]}f\in L^2\cap L^1$ and converges in $L^2$ to $f$. $\Phi : L^2\rightarrow L^2$ is unitary because it is isometric and surjective. It is surjective because its range is closed and also dense. The inverse transform extends to a unitary map $\Psi$ as well. and $\Psi\Phi = I$ on a dense subspace.

Comment: U didnt prove the $ L^2$  convergence u just state it

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471347/question-on-rudins-proof-of-int-nn-hat-f-xieit-xi-d-xi-to-f-in

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts: it is clear that $\Phi$ is unitary and that $\Psi\Phi = I$. The problem I have is that the formula for the inverse transform is only valid on $Y$. i.e on the dense subspace $f\to \hat f$ maps to (from $L^1\cap L^2$, so it does not seem to be a simple case of applying the isometry, as I wanted to do.

Comment: @Abdullahi_A_Ibrahim: thanks for the link. It clears things up nicely. In the comments there, the OP has the same doubts as me.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts: in the link Abdullani sent, they show that for $f_n\in L^1\cap L^2,$ one has $\langle \Psi \Phi f_n,g\rangle=\langle f_n,g\rangle$ for any $g\in L^2$. And this is enough to verify the formula on all of $L^2.$  Rudin's proof is different, uses convolution. In any case, this proves that my approach by itself will not work!

Comment: @Driver8 : Once you know the extended $\Psi$, $\Phi$ are isometric $L^2$ inverses, then you know that $\Psi( \chi_{[n,n]}\Phi f)\rightarrow f$ in $L^2$, which is exactly the first equation of my post.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts: Got it. Once you have the extension to all of $L^2,$ you get $\int \left | \int_{-A}^{A}\hat f(t)e^{ixt}dm(t)-f(x) \right |^2dm(x)=\int \left | (\Psi (\chi \hat f))(x)-f(x) \right |^2dm(x)=\int \left | (\Psi (\chi \hat f))(x)-(\Psi\Phi f)(x) \right |^2dm(x)=\int \left | (\chi \hat f)(t)-(\Phi f)(t) \right |^2dm(t)=\int \left | (\chi \hat f)(t)-\hat f(t) \right |^2dm(x)\to 0$

Comment: @Driver8 : That's it.

Answer (score 2):

Given an $L^2$ function $f(t)$,

define $$\hat{f_n}(s)=\int_{-n}^{n}f(t)e^{-ist}dt$$

It can be easily shown using Plancherel theorem that there is some $g(s) \in L^2$ and $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\hat{f_n}(s)-g(s))^2ds=0$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(g(s))^2ds=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(f(t))^2dt$$

We need to show $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-a}^{a}\left(\frac{1}{{2\pi}}\int_{-n}^{n}g(s)e^{ist}ds-f(t)\right)^2dt=0$$  where $a \in R$

If $ g (s) $ is in $ L^1$ then the convergence is pointwise ae

Proof for  $f(t) $ of compact support and $\in L^2$  :
clearly $f(t) \in L^1$ without loss of generality assume $f(t)=0$ outside $[-\pi,\pi]$ since we can always replace   $f(t)$ with $f(t')$ such as $t=\frac{n}{2\pi} t'$ for $n \in N$ and $t' \in R$.

define $${g}(s)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-n}^{n}f(t)e^{-ist}dt$$

The relationship between fourier transform and fourier series for $f(t)$ above follows from

$$(1)  \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t+u)\frac{sin(n+\frac{1}{2})u}{2sin(u/2)}du-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t+u)\frac{sin(n+\frac{1}{2})u}{u}du)^2dt=0$$

which is simply consequence of dominated convergence theorem and Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma applied to the function $ f (t+u) k (u) $, where $k(u)=\frac{1}{2sin(u/2)}-\frac{1}{u}$  , using remainder term for the Taylor's series of $sin(u/2)$, it easily seen $k(u) $  is bounded over $[-\pi, \pi]$

$$(2)\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-(n+\frac{1}{2})}^{(n+\frac{1}{2})}g(s)e^{ist}ds=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t+u)\frac{sin(n+\frac{1}{2})u}{u}du$$

This can be derived from fubini's theorem and  this theorem : $\mu$ is Lebesgue outer measure, $ A $  is a measurable set with finite measure. For all $n$ ,  $\int_Af_n^2d\mu \le k $ where $ k \in R $ , {$ f_n $} is uniformly integrable

Norm convergence for Fourier series  :
$$(3)  \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t+u)\frac{sin(n+\frac{1}{2})u}{2sin(u/2)}du-f(t))^2dt=0$$

using Riemann Lebesgue Lemma on (2) we have $$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-(n+\frac{1}{2})}^{(n+\frac{1}{2})}g(s)e^{ist}ds=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t+u)\frac{sin(n+\frac{1}{2})u}{u}du$$

Using Norm convergence of fourier series (3), Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, Cauchy-Schwartz Inequality,$a^2+b^2 \ge 2ab$ and (1) and (2) we have:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-(n+\frac{1}{2})}^{n+\frac{1}{2}}g(s)e^{ist}ds-f(t)\right)^2dt=0$$

Proof for $f(t) \in L^2$:

define $f_m=f_{[-m,m]}$ where $m \in N$ and its fourier transform is $\hat{f_m}$

$$\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} f_m=f$$

By Plancherel theorem : $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \hat{f_m}=\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-m}^{m}f(t)e^{-ist}dt=\hat{f}$ in sense of $L^2$

our previous result for function with compact support : $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-n}^{n}\hat{f_m}(s)e^{ist}ds-f_m(t))^2dt =0 $$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-n}^{n}\hat{f_m}(s)e^{ist}ds-f_m(t))^2dt=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-n}^{n}\hat{f_m}(s)e^{ist}ds-f_m(t)_{[-\pi,\pi]})^2dt =\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-n}^{n}\hat{f_m}(s)e^{ist}ds-f(t))^2dt=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-n}^{n}\hat{f_n}(s)e^{ist}ds-f(t))^2dt=0 $$

There is a subsequence {$n$} such that $\hat{f_n} \to \hat{f} $ ae. Let's work with such subsequence

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-n}^{n}\hat{f}(s)e^{ist}ds-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-n}^{n}\hat{f_n}(s)e^{ist}ds)^2dt =$$$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(f(t+u)_{[-\infty,-n]}+f(t+u)_{[n,\infty]})\frac{sin(n+\frac{1}{2})u}{u}du)^2dt $$ $$\le 2(||f(u)_{[-\infty,-n]}+f(u)_{[n,\infty]}||_{L^2}||\frac{sin(n+\frac{1}{2})u}{u}||_{L^2})^{-1/2}$$ by Cauchy-Scwartz ineqaulity

because $a^2+b^2 \ge 2ab$ , it follows from Cauchy-Schwartz inequality that:

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-n}^{n}\hat{f}(s)e^{ist}ds-f(t))^2dt\le$ 
$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(|\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-n}^{n}\hat{f}(s)e^{ist}ds-f_n(t)|+|f_n(t)-f(t)|)^2dt=0 $

we proved the result for some sequence {$n$} to see the result holds for all $n$ we observe that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-(n+1)}^{(n+1)}\hat{f}(s)e^{ist}ds-\int_{-n}^{n}\hat{f}(s)e^{ist}ds)^2dt \le$$$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-(n+1)}^{(-n)}|\hat{f(s)}|ds+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{n}^{(n+1)}|\hat{f(s)}|ds)^2dt \le \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{2\pi}(||\hat{f}_{[-n-1,-n]}||_{L^2}+||\hat{f}_{[n,n+1]}||_{L^2})^2=0$$ by Hölder's Inequality

Comment: I upvoted your nice proof but I wonder if there is there any way to do this without using the Dirichlet kernel? i.e.does it follow from Plancherel, using only the fact that $f\to \hat f$ maps from a dense subspace of $L^2$ namely $L^1\cap L^2$ onto a dense subspace $Y$ of $L^2$ then extends to all of $L^2.$

Comment: @Driver the link i gave u doest require Dirichlet kernel however u need a theorem I stated in my proof regarding integration of uniformly integrable sequence {$f_n$} to prove $$\langle g , \mathcal F^* \mathcal F f \rangle = \langle \mathcal F g , \mathcal F  f\rangle.$$ used by Potato in his proof.

Comment: So you used a specific function to get to the same result. OK. Thanks....